# How is NSURL "copied" during URL loading?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, nsurl, nsurlprotocol

I'm writing a subclass of `NSURL` (along with a partnering subclass of `NSURLProtocol`). I'm intentionally stashing an additional data property on the URL object intended to be retrieved and used in the URL loading. (This is just an experiment; don't judge.)

However, when I test out the class combo by creating one of these custom URL objects and then trying to load from it...

```
NSData * data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:myURL];
```

...my URL protocol gets handed an *actual* `NSURL` instance to inspect, not the instance that I created. Its `absoluteString` is what I expect-- in other words, the loading internals have copied my original URL to a new one-- but it's not my custom subclass, so it's missing the extra property.

Note that my `NSURL` subclass correctly overrides `-copyWithZone:` for NSCopying compliance and both `-initWithCoder:` and `-encodeWithCoder:` for `NSSecureCoding` compliance. This should ensure that anyone making a shallow or deep copy of an instance of my class should get a full, correct copy. But none of these methods are called during this process. (Neither is `absoluteString`, `path`, `relativeString`, etc.)

Someone's "copying" out my URL's (string) contents without calling any of the methods I'd expect to see. I suppose another Foundation class could just be bypassing the public interface and accessing a private/internal property to do this.

Can anyone confirm if NSURL is fundamentally un-subclassable? Or if I might be missing something?

Comment: A guess would be that something in the toll-free bridge to CFURL fails to call into Objective-C for some reason but I can't see anything obvious in http://opensource.apple.com/source/CF/CF-855.17/CFURL.c

Comment: It would help if you showed more relevant code.

Comment: This is long past usefulness for me, but to future travelers: there isn't really any relevant code-- question is about whether there's a way to subclass `NSURL` and see that subclass instance appear in the URLProtocol object.